# Getting a blank screen after copying project in my server

Tags: 7

I am fairly new to Drupal.

I just got an already existing Drupal project and want to install it.

I copied it to: /var/www/html/myprojects/mydrupalproject

Then I got this error in my error.log from apache2:

> [Thu May 03 17:55:41.603774 2018] [php7:notice] [pid 11604] [client
>   127.0.0.1:41930] PHP Notice:  Constant DATE_RFC7231 already defined in /var/www/html/myprojects/mydrupalproject/includes/bootstrap.inc on
>   line 258, referer: http://127.0.0.1/myprojects/
>
> [Thu May 03 17:55:41.604601 2018] [php7:error] [pid 11604] [client
>   127.0.0.1:41930] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/var/www/html/myprojects/mydrupalproject/profiles/clusters_public/modules/contrib/apc/drupal_apc_cache.inc'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in
>   /var/www/html/myprojects/mydrupalproject/includes/bootstrap.inc on
>   line 2632, referer: http://127.0.0.1/myprojects/

So I tried to use the original .htaccess info in case it was the problem but I still get exactly the same error in the log. Any help?

Comment: Looks like you have PHP7. What version is your Drupal 7? Also check to make sure the filesystem permissions are set correctly so that www-data (or whatever user your webserver is running as) has read/write permissions on the codebase. `Failed opening required ...` *usually* means file permission issues or the file doesn't actually exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things to check
1- Check what PHP version on your server, you will need PHP 5 not PHP 7.

2- Make sure you update the $base_url in you settings.php file, assuming you copied that from your local